# Check if ArcGIS Server 10.0 Service is running and start if not

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

I am using AGSSOM.exe to start and stop ArcGIS Server 10.0 MapServices. I would like to slightly adapt this script to first check if the services are running, and then to start them if they have stopped.

Does anyone know if this is possible and how?

Comment: Windows will tell you if a service is running. Are you looking to see if the service is responsive?

Comment: I meant MapServices in AGS, not Windows services.Sorry

Comment: I could also use an answer to this, we've been discussing a similar solution at work recently (as a better alternative to the current method, "wait until a user notices and complains")

Comment: Are you asking about trying to monitor the service?  Looking at the source code for AGSSOM, sending a start command to already running service doesn't seem to error so you could just "start" your service and it will start if stopped or paused.

Comment: @Erica Building an alerting system is possible in any web-enabled language (Python, Java, C#, JavaScript, even 'C' if you're a glutton for punishment). All you need to know is the REST endpoint URL and the kind of notification.

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you.  This uses a combination of Python and the AGSSOM utility to create a list of the running map services and then stop any services in that list.

```
import os, subprocess 

#Get list of currently running map services 
stream = os.popen('D:\GIS\Admin\AGSSOMv10.0\AGSSOM.exe -list') 
mapservices = stream.readlines() 
lstStarted = [] 

for item in mapservices: 
    itemSplit = item.split(',') 
    if len(itemSplit) > 1: 
        if itemSplit[1].find("Started.") > -1: 
            lstStarted.append(itemSplit[0]) 



#Restart previously running map services 
for mapservice in lstStarted: 
    subprocess.call(['D:\GIS\Admin\AGSSOMv10.0\AGSSOM.exe', '-x', mapservice])
```